# Python copy list issue

Tags: python

I don't know what's wrong here, I'm sure someone here can help though.  I have a list `mylst` (list of lists) that's being copied and passed into the method `foo`.  `foo` iterates through the list and replaces the first element in the row with a passed in var and returns the altered list.  I print the list and I see it gives me what I expect.  I repeat that process again with another copy of `mylst` and a different passed in var.  So the two returned lists should be different; however when I check the first list again I see that it's now the second list, also `mylst` has changed to that of the second list.  Am I not copying the list correctly?  I'm copying it with the `mylst[:]` method.  Also another interesting observation is that all the list IDs are different.  Doesn't that mean it's a different list than the others?  Here's an example of my problem.

```
def printer(lst):
    print "--------------"
    for x in lst:
        print x
    print "--------------\n"

def foo(lst, string):

    for x in lst:
        x[0] = string

    print "in foo"
    for x in lst:
        print x
    print "in foo\n"

    return lst

mylst = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
print "mylst", id(mylst), "\n"

first = foo(mylst[:], "first")
print "first", id(first)
printer(first) # Correct

second = foo(mylst[:], "second")
print "second", id(second)
printer(second) # Correct

print "first", id(first)
printer(first) # Wrong

print "mylst", id(mylst)
printer(mylst) # Wrong
```

Here's the print out on my computer

```
mylst 3076930092 

in foo
['first', 2, 3]
['first', 5, 6]
in foo

first 3076930060
--------------
['first', 2, 3]
['first', 5, 6]
--------------

in foo
['second', 2, 3]
['second', 5, 6]
in foo

second 3076929996
--------------
['second', 2, 3]
['second', 5, 6]
--------------

first 3076930060
--------------
['second', 2, 3]
['second', 5, 6]
--------------

mylst 3076930092
--------------
['second', 2, 3]
['second', 5, 6]
--------------
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `lst[:]` trick makes a copy of *one* level of list. You've got nested lists, so you may want to have a look at the services offered by the [`copy`](http://docs.python.org/library/copy.html) standard module.

In particular:

```
first = foo(copy.deepcopy(mylst), "first")
```

Comment: do you know why the IDs are different?

Comment: The IDs of the *first* list are different, but you'll find that the IDs of the lists *contained in* the first one are the same.

Comment: `deepcopy` always makes the magic, I use it almost blindly in these scenarios

Answer (score 0):

You aren't making another copy of mylist.  Both times you call foo, you are passing the same object reference and modifying the same list.